# About unitary group of a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Is unitary group of a von Neumann algebra is locally compact in some topology? Can we make sense of integration with respect to Haar measure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unitary group is compact for finite von Neumann algebras of type I.
It is also locally compact for the discrete topology.

Other than these two cases, the set of unitary elements
can be equipped with the ultraweak topology, which yields a compact topolpogical
space but for which the operation of multiplication
is not continuous, or it can be equipped with the norm or ultrastrong topologies,
which are not locally compact, but do give a topological group.
In either case, the Haar theorem is not applicable.